# How can I find CID from ADB shell?

Tags: adb, shell, build.prop

I need to know the *CID* of an HTC 10 but,

```
adb shell getprop ro.cid
```

is unresponsive. Also

```
$ fastboot devices
FA**********     fastboot
$ fastboot oem readcid
FAILED (remote: 'unknown command')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```

Also, `grep -ril cid` is unsuccessful on root.

How can I get the *CID* info on my Android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to get cid info with following command.

`adb shell getprop|grep cid`

```
$adb shell getprop|grep cid
[ro.boot.cid]: [HTC__M27]
```

Comment: Why not simply `adb shell getprop ro.boot.cid`?

Comment: Generally, getprobe ro.* commands are not efficient in my scenario.